# Проблема с отправкой формы Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery

Что здесь не верно ?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").submit(function(){  
        var options = {  
        target: "#1",  
        status: $("#1").html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />'),
        success: function() {  
            $('#1').fadeIn('fast');  
        };  
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);  
        }  
        return false; 
    });
    });
    </head>
    <body>

    </script>
    <div id='1'>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" action='md5.php'>
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="submit" value="test">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Автор, вы мой ответ к этому вопросу читали в вашей предыдущей теме? И зачем было дублировать тему, могли бы там выложить свой доработанный код!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
    // пишем "загрузка"
    $(this).load( // ну или $('#1').load(...).
        $('#form1').attr('action'),
        {a: $('#form1 input[name="a"]').val()},
        function(){
            // загрузилось!
        }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Жуквери и больше ничего. А #1 переименуйте хотя бы в #div1, потому что id **обязан** начинаться с буквы.
`http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp`